# C# Memory.Span Unexpectedly Slow

Tags: c#

While experimenting with the new `Span<byte>` and `Memory<byte>` features I found that using `Memory<byte>` was much slower parsing binary data than I expected compared to other methods of interacting with a byte array.

I set up a benchmark test suite that reads a single integer from an array, using a variety of methods, and found that Memory was the slowest.  It was slower than Span, as expected, but surprisingly it was also slower than direct usage of the array, as well as my own homegrown version of what I expect Memory to be similar to, internally.

```cs
// Suite of tests comparing various ways to read an offset int from an array
public class BinaryTests
{
    static byte[] arr = new byte[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    static Memory<byte> mem = arr.AsMemory();
    static HomegrownMemory memTest = new HomegrownMemory(arr);

    [Benchmark]
    public int StraightArrayBitConverter()
    {
        return BitConverter.ToInt32(arr, 1);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public int MemorySlice()
    {
        return BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32LittleEndian(mem.Slice(1).Span);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public int MemorySliceToSize()
    {
        return BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32LittleEndian(mem.Slice(1, 4).Span);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public int MemorySpanSlice()
    {
        return BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32LittleEndian(mem.Span.Slice(1));
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public int MemorySpanSliceToSize()
    {
        return BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32LittleEndian(mem.Span.Slice(1, 4));
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public int HomegrownMemorySlice()
    {
        return BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32LittleEndian(memTest.Slice(1).Span);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public int HomegrownMemorySliceToSize()
    {
        return BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32LittleEndian(memTest.Slice(1, 4).Span);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public int HomegrownMemorySpanSlice()
    {
        return BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32LittleEndian(memTest.Span.Slice(1));
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public int HomegrownMemorySpanSliceToSize()
    {
        return BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32LittleEndian(memTest.Span.Slice(1, 4));
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public int SpanSlice()
    {
        return BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32LittleEndian(arr.AsSpan().Slice(1));
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public int SpanSliceToSize()
    {
        return BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32LittleEndian(arr.AsSpan().Slice(1, 4));
    }
}

// Personal "implementation" of Memory<T>, for testing
struct HomegrownMemory
{
    byte[] _arr;
    int _startPos;
    int _length;

    public HomegrownMemory(byte[] b)
    {
        this._arr = b;
        this._startPos = 0;
        this._length = b.Length;
    }

    public Span<byte> Span => _arr.AsSpan(start: _startPos, length: _length);

    public HomegrownMemory Slice(int start)
    {
        return new HomegrownMemory()
        {
            _arr = _arr,
            _startPos = _startPos + start,
            _length = _length - start
        };
    }

    public HomegrownMemory Slice(int start, int length)
    {
        return new HomegrownMemory()
        {
            _arr = _arr,
            _startPos = _startPos + start,
            _length = length
        };
    }
}
```

Here are the BenchmarkNet results of the above code:

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.11.5, OS=Windows 10.0.17134.765 (1803/April2018Update/Redstone4)
Intel Core i7-4790K CPU 4.00GHz (Haswell), 1 CPU, 8 logical and 4 physical cores
Frequency=3984652 Hz, Resolution=250.9629 ns, Timer=TSC
.NET Core SDK=2.1.700-preview-009618
  [Host]     : .NET Core 2.1.11 (CoreCLR 4.6.27617.04, CoreFX 4.6.27617.02), 64bit RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET Core 2.1.11 (CoreCLR 4.6.27617.04, CoreFX 4.6.27617.02), 64bit RyuJIT
|                         Method |      Mean |     Error |    StdDev | Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
|------------------------------- |----------:|----------:|----------:|------:|------:|------:|----------:|
|      StraightArrayBitConverter | 1.0832 ns | 0.0323 ns | 0.0270 ns |     - |     - |     - |         - |
|                    MemorySlice | 5.8882 ns | 0.0654 ns | 0.0612 ns |     - |     - |     - |         - |
|              MemorySliceToSize | 6.0191 ns | 0.0983 ns | 0.0919 ns |     - |     - |     - |         - |
|                MemorySpanSlice | 5.0230 ns | 0.0626 ns | 0.0555 ns |     - |     - |     - |         - |
|          MemorySpanSliceToSize | 5.0189 ns | 0.0335 ns | 0.0313 ns |     - |     - |     - |         - |
|           HomegrownMemorySlice | 3.9217 ns | 0.0419 ns | 0.0392 ns |     - |     - |     - |         - |
|     HomegrownMemorySliceToSize | 1.5233 ns | 0.0199 ns | 0.0186 ns |     - |     - |     - |         - |
|       HomegrownMemorySpanSlice | 0.8301 ns | 0.0243 ns | 0.0227 ns |     - |     - |     - |         - |
| HomegrownMemorySpanSliceToSize | 0.8303 ns | 0.0223 ns | 0.0208 ns |     - |     - |     - |         - |
|                      SpanSlice | 0.6891 ns | 0.0241 ns | 0.0214 ns |     - |     - |     - |         - |
|                SpanSliceToSize | 0.6804 ns | 0.0174 ns | 0.0163 ns |     - |     - |     - |         - |
```

All of these timings make a lot of sense to me, except the `Memory<T>` timings, which are all slower than I would've expected.

It was my understanding that `Memory<T>` was simply an implementation of `Span<T>` that could live on the heap, eg.. not a ref struct.

I would have expected it to perform slower than Span, but at least par if not a little faster than the Straight Array implementation.   The results I achieved with my homegrown version are the results I expected out of`Memory<T>`

Is there something fundamental I'm missing here about the use case for `Memory<T>`, or what it's trying to accomplish?  Something seems off about my understanding after seeing these results.

EDIT:
After Cowen's comment, I located the Memory source code and took a look.  It does seem to be doing a lot when retrieving the span, specifically checking and casting its generic object field to find out what type it is in order to cast properly.

I'm surprised they didn't give use different Memory options and/or provide a Memory factory to construct classes with more strongly typed internal data fields.  Instead they opted to have a field that is an object that has to constantly be checked/casted to get at the Span, which is something I feel like should/would be happening constantly during use.

I'm still curious as to why they designed Memory this way and more importantly, what the use cases are given it's designed this way.  I feel like a lot of people who are utilizing Span/Memory are after the speed benefits and the generic object field seems to encourage not using it.

Comment: You probably need to redesign your benchmark to identify the culprit here. The 2nd through 5th methods all call Memory<T>.Span. If you take a look at the source for that method it is fairly involved. I suspect that method is taking up most of the time.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. 8)  I made an edit after looking at the source as you suggested.

Comment: So does anyone know the purpose of Memory<T>?

Answer (score 5):

It is important to remember that `Span<T>` and `Memory<T>` exist to do more than perform well relative to arrays, and that performance itself is multi-faceted.

For example, a big reason for their existence is to enable developers to write algorithms that can work with contiguous memory in general, regardless of type, in part or in whole, and to do *that* in an efficient and safe way.

Your homegrown memory type is faster than `Memory<T>` in this instance, but that is because it does not have the capabilities of `Memory<T>`.  For example, should you use it in a string parsing algorithm, you may find that it performs very poorly and requires extra code due to the need to create and fill new arrays every time you encounter a new string or need to pass a subset of a string to a method that does not accept `startIndex` or `length`.  You would have to design your algorithm around this limitation, and even if you were able to minimize the impact on performance, doing so would have a negative impact on your code's readability, time spent writing it, etc.  `Span<T>` and `Memory<T>` do not have this pitfall.

`Span<T>` is lightning quick because it can safely store a ref, living on the stack.  `Memory<T>` has similar requirements in addition to a requirement to live on the heap, meaning it cannot benefit from ref or pointers.  The best the platform has to offer in this case is `Object`, and while that is undoubtedly a little slower than a strongly typed array, it is *much* faster than making many unnecessary copies of data.  It is not perfect for every situation, but in many situations, it may be enough to allow developers to write a single, general-purpose method where they might otherwise feel compelled to write 2-8 uglier overloads.  There is a lot of value in that.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and thoughts!  I don't disagree it's got some nice use cases.  I'm more just surprised that there isn't some sort of mechanism to allow for heap-backed arrays to make use of the span style slicing without the speed loss.  The span API is great, and to have to sacrifice speed to be able to write in that style when backed by a legit array seems odd.  Seems like there could be some middleground, even if it was a 3rd structure that replaced my HomegrownMemory.  Shouldn't need to choose between speed, pre-span APIs, or defining ones own HomegrownMemory.